# How to create path to file in web directory in Symfony/Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How to create path to file in web directory in Symfony/Twig ?

Doing this way:

`<a href="files/1.jpg">1</a>'`

add 
 `files/1.jpg` to opened url `http://localhost/documents/`, so results in `http://localhost/documents/files/1.jpg`

Doing this way:

`{{ asset('files/1.jpg') }}`

generate: 
`/files/1.jpg`

I want:

`http://localhost/web/files/1.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look there https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#linking-to-assets

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
    <img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('images/logo.png')) }}" alt="Symfony!" />
```